# Good() and fail() understanding

Tags: c++, iostream

Input: 10 20 30
Output: 60

Input: 10 a 20
Output: 10

Because it got somethings that is not a number. And I cant understand how `good()` and `fail()` work here.

```cpp
int sum(istringstream & text) noexcept {
    int sum = 0; 
    int current = 0; 
    while (text.good())
    {
        text >> current; 
        if (!text.fail())
        {
            sum += current;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation on [`std::basic_ios::good`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good), and [`std::basic_ios::fail`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail)?

Comment: Yes sir , but I cant get it , how the function knows that is a number or a word/letter :/

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "_how the function knows that is a number or a word/letter_". Did you even read the documentation?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius OP said they read it and didn't understand. It might be more helpful to ask a probing question or point out what specific parts of the documentation explain the issue.

Comment: `current` is an integer, it will not accept "words", only numbers. Trying to insert a number will trigger the failbit on your stream. See my answer below.

Comment: @parktomatomi There's reading the documentation, and there's skimming the documentation. Since the 3rd line, on the documentation was "_See [ios_base::iostate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) for the list of conditions that set failbit or badbit._", which explains under which conditions `failbit` is set, which is what `fail` returns, which is what appears that the asker is asking: the suspicion arose, that he didn't even read the documentation.

Comment: Per [`std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt): "*If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), ... and **failbit** is set.*" - hence why `good()` is false and `fail()` is true when `text >> current` encounters `a` in the input. Also, `text >> current; if (!text.fail()) { ... }` should be `if (text >> current) { ... }` instead.

Answer (score 1):

### Fail

You try to read something that is not a number into an integer. This will trigger the failbit in your stringstream.
The failbit basically prevents you from using that stream altogether (consider your stream "broken").
The failbit will remain on until the object is destroyed OR until you manually remove it with `text.clear()`.

---

> **std::ios::fail**
> Check whether either failbit or badbit is set
> Returns true if either (or both) the failbit or the badbit error state flags is set for the stream.
> At least one of these flags is set when an error occurs during an input operation.
>
> failbit is generally set by an operation when the error is related to the internal logic of the operation itself; further operations on the stream may be possible.

Also check out this table
[image]

If you look at the fail() column under "functions to check state flags", you'll see that `fail()` returns true under 2 conditions:

1. Logical error on i/o operation
2. Read/writing error on i/o operation (Your case)

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/)

---

### Good

As for `good()`, it checks that there are currently no flags (see table above for the flags).

> Returns true if none of the stream's error state flags (eofbit, failbit and badbit) is set.

Comment: A comparison with `good()` and how they differ would also be nice.